# Transferring files between two PHP servers

Tags: php, web-services, api

I want to transfer a file from 1 php server (A) to another php server (B).
The servers are located in different domains.
I was thinking about encrypting the file on server A and then sending a post request to server B, including the the file in the POST headers, and decrypt it.

Do you any tips and recommendation about that?
  Should I put the url of the file in the POST headers or the file itself?
Can you suggest a better way to do that?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have shell access to both machines? Do you have control over user policies for one or both machines?

Comment: I have control for machine B and I'm writing an API for machine A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't put files in the POST, especially if they're big files. I'm sure there are security concerns to worry about with doing that as well, but the file size issue would just be nothing but headaches.

If you're going to be transferring files, why not use FTP. After all, that's what it was made for. Take a look at the [PHP manual for FTP functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.ftp.php).

Comment: Yes, I was worried about the file size too.

Comment: Should I upload the file from A to B? Or download it from B to A? Which one is better?

Comment: I don't know which would be better. If you can open a directory on the receiving server and place a file, I guess uploading it would be easier as the receiving server doesn't need to know about the file. If you wanted to download the file, the server would need to somehow be aware of the file's existence to know to grab it and download it.

Answer (score 2):

How about Server B receives the file, sends a post with a link and temporary credentials to Server A.  Server A then downloads the file from Server B over HTTPS using the link and credentials from the post?

Comment: I didn't understand... I want to get a file from A to B. I have control on B.

Answer (score 0):

if the php box is running server you could use scp, like ftp but it automatically encrypts any data going onto the wire.  there are some scp stacks for windows as well, but you might be better off with sftp in that case.